# how to convert a WPF ellipse to motion path using C#

Tags: c#, path, blend, motion

Hi all
Its hard to explain what I need and I really don't know if that is actually can be accomplished or not.
anyway, I have created two circles using blend.

now what I want is to convert the first circle to a motion path then attach the second circle to that path and then generate a storyboard and lastly play the animation.

I want to accomplish this programmatically using C# I don't want to do this from xaml or from microsoft blend.
is there anyway I can do this? any tutorial or advice will be appreciated.

regards,

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to do this in XAML? Just curious :)

Comment: Yes I want to make dynamic motion paths and dynamic storyboard animations. for example I have a textblock contains specific text I want to convert this textblock to a motion path so I can use an ellipse to move on that path(or the text inside the textblock)